# Self in init params

Tags: swift, types, initialization

I would like to use Self in init parameters like so:

```
class A {
    public init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: Self) -> Void)? = nil) {...}
}
```

I know I could use "A" in this place, but I would like to achieve that if some class inherits from A, then it's initializer would know operation as it's class type and not as just A. So for example if I wrote:

```
class B: A {
    public init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: Self) -> Void)? = nil) {...}
    public func fooOnlyInB() {}
}
```

I could then use:

```
let b = B { (operation) in
    operation.fooOnlyInB()
}
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Interesting! I wanted to see whether this could work by making a protocol with a `Self` requirement in `init`, but I came across the error mentioned in [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32999293/3769927).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Self` or `A` in each of the initialisers, you can simply override each subclass' initialiser to use its own type as `operation`.

This works because `A`'s initialiser states that `operation` should be a type that conforms to `A`, and when you override it you have the liberty to use a subclass of `A` as `operation` instead. However, if you change `operation` to an unrelated type such as `String` or `Int`, the compiler will not override the existing initialiser.

Firstly, define `A` with its `init`:

```
class A {
    init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: A) -> Void)?) {...}
}
```

Now to create a subclass, you must override `init` using the subclass' type as `operation` instead. In your call to `super.init`, force upcast `operation` (`$0`) to your subclass' type, and call `finishBlock` with this casted `operation`.

```
class B: A {
    override init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: B) -> Void)?) {
        // Perform custom initialisation...
        super.init { finishBlock?($0 as! B) }
    }

    func fooOnlyInB() {
        print("foo")
    }
}
```

`B`'s initialiser now passes `B` as `operation`, which means that you don't need to cast it yourself anymore! This is thanks to the fact that you can override an `init` with a more specific type, in this case `B`.

```
let b = B { operation in
    operation.fooOnlyInB() // prints "foo"
}
```

Comment: You are right, this is some solution, although not perfect. I don't like the fact that I need to explicitly override init to have this working, and also that instead of just passing finishBlock as an argument I need to create another block that executes finishBlock from subclass. But still this is some solution which is better then nothing. I will definitely use it, but it's a shame it is required to do such a workaround. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, you cannot do this directly, as `Self` is currently only available in protocols or as the return type of a method in a class.

However, you *can* workaround this by using a protocol extension in order to declare the initialiser:

```
protocol AProtocol : A {}
// Pre Swift 5:
// protocol AProtocol {
//   init()
// }

extension AProtocol {
  init(completion: ((Self) -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.init()
    completion?(self)
  }
}

class A : AProtocol {
  required init() {}
}

class B : A {
  func fooOnlyInB() {
    print("foo in B")
  }
}


let a = A(completion: {
  print($0) // A
})

let b = B(completion: {
  $0.fooOnlyInB() // foo in B
})
```

This isn't however a perfect solution, as it makes it difficult for `B` to add its own stored properties, as they'll have to be given default values in order to satisfy the `required init()`.

But really, as far as I'm aware, there's no real technical reason why you shouldn't be able to use `Self` as a parameter of a closure method argument in a class.

Function parameters are contravariant, so `(A) -> Void` is a subtype of `(B) -> Void`. Therefore an `((A) -> Void) -> T` can be overridden by an `((B) -> Void) -> T` (applying contravariance again), so the use of `Self` as the parameter of a function passed to a method should be perfectly legal.

It's just something the language doesn't fully support yet ([SR-10121](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10121)).

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I don't think it is possible because you can use `Self` only in protocols as it is just a placeholder for the type that is going to conform to that protocol. It is not a real type like `A` or `B` so you can't use that upon defining classes as if it is `Any` or `AnyObject`.

So let's create a protocol which forces conforming types to implement `init(finishBlock:)` initializer:

```
protocol BlockInitializable {
  init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: Self) -> Void)?)
}

class A: BlockInitializable {
  init() {}

  convenience required init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: A) -> Void)?) {
    self.init()
    finishBlock?(self)
  }
}
```

and you'll get the following error:

> Protocol "Blocked" requirement **init(finishBlock:)** can not be satisifed by a non-final class `(A)` because it uses "Self" in a non-parameter, non-result type position.

and what's worse you'll lose the generic type `Self` of parameter *operation*.

To fix this, you should mark your class as final or use *struct* which is a final type. However, you'll lose the ability of subclassing those types. The reason why you have to do that and why you can't use `Self` in subclassed types is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self) so I recommend you go take a look at it.

I'll go with the latter option and use struct:

```
protocol Initializable {
  init()
}

protocol BlockInitializable: Initializable {
  init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: Self) -> Void)?)
}

extension BlockInitializable {
  init(finishBlock: ((_ operation: Self) -> Void)?) {
    self.init()
    finishBlock?(self)
  }
}
```

then define `A` and `B` as struct:

```
struct A: BlockInitializable {

}

struct B: BlockInitializable {
  func fooOnlyInB() {
    print("Only in B")
  }
}
```

and you'll be able to do the following:

```
let blockA = A { operation in
  print("Only in A")
}

let blockB = B { operation in
  operation.fooOnlyInB()
}
```

You can download the playground from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3q7bt1zf59gw1et/AAAqaLCT4yC3UzORTbHGI5Sca?dl=0).

Comment: The whole point of this is that this class needs inheritance, so I guess there is nothing I can do about it - parameter "operation" needs to stay defined as A and in subclasses I need to cast it to preferred B (operation as? B). 
Too bad, it would be nice to have this working. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes that's a bummer. The basic reason of that is Swift strictly needs to know the type of `Self` in compile time. The other link I shared is explaining it much better.