# Extract self-properties in block-method

Tags: swift, properties, block, subclassing

I have some trouble in understanding my specific request, in Swift.
There is a class named Origin and multiple its subclasses.
How I can update my block-method written ONLY in Origin class?

```
class Origin: NSObject {
    func mod(_ block: (() throws -> Void)) {
        try! block()
    } 
}
```

I need use mod from all Origin subclasses, and I need to have this usage effect:

```
var originSubclassObject = OriginSubclass() 
originSubclassObject.mod {
    .age = 12 //age is OriginSubclass property
    .name = "Bob" //name is OriginSubclass property
}
```

So, you see, I need extract OriginSubclass properties for using in mod-block. I need to create usage exactly likes in usage effect code (extract mod-caller properties from ".").
Thanks all for help!

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356615/2976878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider a protocol with a default implementation, e.g.:

```
protocol Modifiable { }

extension Modifiable {
    func mod(_ block: ((Self) throws -> Void)) {
        try! block(self)
    }
}

class Origin: Modifiable { }

class OriginSubclass: Origin {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
}
```

And then:

```
let originSubclassObject = OriginSubclass()
originSubclassObject.mod { object in
    object.age = 12
    object.name = "Bob"
}
```

Or

```
let originSubclassObject = OriginSubclass()
originSubclassObject.mod {
    $0.age = 12
    $0.name = "Bob"
}
```

Or, if that base class was only there for the `mod` method, you could lose it entirely:

```
protocol Modifiable { }

extension Modifiable {
    func mod(_ block: ((Self) throws -> Void)) {
        try! block(self)
    }
}

class MyObject: Modifiable {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
}
```

And

```
let myObject = MyObject()
myObject.mod { object in
    object.age = 12
    object.name = "Bob"
}
```

Or

```
let myObject = MyObject()
myObject.mod {
    $0.age = 12
    $0.name = "Bob"
}
```