# Swift function with generic closure argument

Tags: swift

I have parent and child classes:

```
class Animal {
   func write(_ block: ((_ animal: Animal) -> Void) ) throws {
      block(self)
   }
}

class Dog: Animal {
   var name: ""
}
```

I need to change name using *write* function. Now I do it like:

```
let dog = Dog()
dog.write { ($0 as! Dog).name = "Bob" }
```

But I want to do it like (without modification of `Dog`):

```
dog.write { $0.name = "Bob" }
```

How to do this?

Comment: Then `Animal` must have the parameter name. Or you have to override the method in `Dog`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I want to achieve result without modification of `Dog` or adding parameters to `Animal`

Comment: `Self` is the tool you're looking for – though unfortunately we don't have [universal `Self`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) yet, so you have to hack it by using a protocol extension. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356615/2976878

Comment: @SergeyDi i think you need to put name in animal or override method as jay do

Comment: @SergeyDi `name` is Dog-specific property which means that in your particular scenario you *must* cast Animal to Dog.

Comment: Unrelated but the underscore and the parameter level in the closure are pointless because they are not used at all in Swift 3+ `func write(_ block: ((Animal) -> Void) ) throws {` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need the block argument to depend on the class of the object that the method is being called on. One way to achieve this is with a protocol that uses `Self`:

```
protocol Writable { }

extension Writable {
    // Self can be used in protocols, and point to the concrete implementation
    // of the protocol
    func write(_ block: ((Self) -> Void) ) throws {
        block(self)
    }
}

// Just need to declare the conformance, all subclasses will inherit it
class Animal: Writable { }

class Dog: Animal {
    var name = "Unnamed"
}

let dog = Dog()
print("Dog name:", dog.name)
try dog.write { $0.name = "Bob" }
print("Dog name:", dog.name)
```

As expected, the above code will print

```
Dog name: Unnamed
Dog name: Bob
```

Note that `write` is not part of the protocol requirements, you can add it to the list of protocol methods, however using `Self` as part of the protocol requirements will limit the places where the protocol can be used (collections, non-generic function arguments, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you override the `write` function in the `Dog` class as well? Something like below would do.

```
class Animal {
    func write(_ block: ((_ animal: Animal) -> Void) ) throws {
        block(self)
    }
}

class Dog: Animal {
    var name =  ""

    override func write(_ block: ((Dog) -> Void)) throws {
        block(self)
    }
}

let myDog = Dog()
try?myDog.write{  $0.name = "Bob" }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to achieve result without modification of `Dog`

Comment: then you need the name attribute in the parent class.