# Self type as argument in closure

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible for an instance of a `UIView` to call a method which executes a closure, and inside that closure referring to the same instance? This is the non-generic version:

```
import UIKit

public extension UIView {
    func layout(from: (UIView) -> ()) {
        from(self)
    }
}
```

When I call it with a UILabel for example, I do not have access to e.g. the text aligment. Is it possible that inside the closure I can refer to the UILabel? I would expect something like this would work:

```
func layout(from: (Self) -> ()) {
    from(self)
}
```

But it doesn't compile. Is there a workaround? This is what I want:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)

label.layout { $0.textAlignment = .natural } // Currenly not working, since $0 = UIView.
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `label` instead of `$0`?

Comment: @MoAbdul-Hameed This is a simplified version of something bigger, so don't mind the actual code :)

Comment: Does `func layout<T>(from: (T) -> ()) where T == Self` work?

Comment: @Alexander no it does not compile

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356615/2976878 – you can currently use a protocol extension to work around this limitation until it's implemented ([SR-10121](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10121)).

Comment: @Hamish vadian gave an answer with protocol extensions, or is there another way?

Comment: @J.Doe Unfortunately currently that's the only workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different approach: Protocol Extension with associated type.

```
protocol Layout {
    associatedtype View : UIView = Self
    func layout(from: (View) -> ())
}

extension Layout where Self : UIView {
    func layout(from: (Self) -> ()) {
        from(self)
    }
}

extension UIView : Layout {}
```

---

```
let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
label.layout { $0.textAlignment = .natural }
```

Comment: You don't need to declare an `associatedtype` for this to work (or any protocol requirements for that matter). You could also declare the protocol as `protocol Layout : UIView` to restrict it to being conformed by `UIView` (and then remove the constraint from the extension).

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do it.

Firstly, you could use the [closures' variable capturing system](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) in order to directly use the variable inside the closure, without passing it as an argument.

```
public extension UIView {
    func layout(from: () -> ()) {
        from()
    }
}

label.layout { label.textAlignment = .natural }
```

Otherwise, if you want to pass a generic `UIView` and change the behaviour accordingly to the specific one - since it looks like you know for sure what type you are working on - you can use a downcast:

```
public extension UIView {
    func layout(from: (UIView) -> ()) {
        from(self)
    }
}

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)

label.layout { ($0 as! UILabel).textAlignment = .natural }
```

Anyway, why are you doing:

```
label.layout { $0.textAlignment = .natural }
```

instead of:

```
label.textAlignment = .natural
```

Is there any particular reason not to do it? I imagine there's something bigger behind the scenes, I'm just curious.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. The code in the question isn't the real code, but a simplified version. When using the closure method as you described at the top of your answer, I do not get an argument of type `self` (which is the question).

Comment: Hello!
I see, what about the second piece of the answer? I mean, the downcast. Is it too *dirty*?

Comment: Yes, I do not want to downcast everytime I use it, but still thank you for your explaination and answer :)