# Initializing type of `self`

Tags: swift

This works

```
class Die {
    let faces: Int

    required init(faces: Int) {
        self.faces = faces
    }

    func yahtzeeDice() -> [Die] {
        return [Die](repeating: type(of: self).init(faces: 6), count: 5)
    }
}
```

This seems to violate DRY. It is possible to refer to `Die` indirectly in the `yahtzeeDice` function?

Comment: Are you talking about the `[Die]` in the method signature of `yahtzeeDice()` or the body? The latter could be replaced by `Array`, as the element type of `Die` can be inferred.

Comment: Unrelated: Why is `yahtzeeDice()` an instance method? You could make it a `static`/`class` method and just use `self` rather than `type(of: self)`.

Comment: You cannot use `[Self]` in the signature because array is a struct and if `A : B` then `[A]` and `[B]` are still unrelated types.

Comment: Also note that the repeating initializer of the `[Die]` array above with instantiate _a single_ `Die` instance, thereafter repeat the reference to this instance `5` times in the array (since `Die` is reference type). I.e., all members of `[Die]` hold a strong reference to the same underlying `Die` instance.

Comment: What is the purpose of referring to it indirectly, i.e. what problem are you trying to solve? Do you plan to change the name of the class very often?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the repeating initializer of the `[Die]` array in your question will instantiate *a single* `Die` instance, thereafter repeat the reference to this instance 5 times in the array (since `Die` is reference type). I.e., all members of `[Die]` in your example hold a strong reference to the same underlying `Die` instance. So remember to avoid the repeating array initializer if you use reference types.

---

Now, you could construct a protocol that provides a default implementation of a blueprinted `static` dice supplier method, which supplies an array of `Self` instances, using some other blueprinted initializer.

```
// the 'class' requirement not strictly needed here, but it holds semantic
// value to explain the 'map' call rather than using array:s 'repeating' 
// initializer in in the default implementation below
protocol DiceFactory: class {
    init(faces: Int, id: Int)
    static func dice(_ n: Int) -> [Self]
}
extension DiceFactory {
    static func dice(_ n: Int) -> [Self] {
        return (1...n).map { Self.init(faces: 6, id: $0) }
    }
}
```

If you mark your `Dice` class `final` (why `final`? refer to the linked Q&A below), you'll have access to this default implementation directly when conforming to the `DiceFactory` protocol.

```
final class Die: DiceFactory {
    let id: Int
    let faces: Int

    init(faces: Int, id: Int) {
        self.faces = faces
        self.id = id
    }
}

let myDice = Die.dice(5)
myDice.forEach { print($0, $0.id) }
    /* Die 1
       Die 2
       Die 3
       Die 4
       Die 5 */
```

But the again, do you have a good reason not to explicitly type out `Die`?

See also:

- [How do you implement protocol methods that return covariant Selfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999293/how-do-you-implement-protocol-methods-that-return-covariant-selfs)

Comment: One minor improvement, you can use `(1...n).map { Self.init(...) }` to generate the array.

Comment: Note that the use of `Array(repeating:count:)` *may* be intentional, given that `Die` instances are immutable (it's possible OP is just using a class for inheritance – if this isn't the case, then it should definitely be a `struct` instead).